# If $y = a\sin{x} + b\cos{x} +C$ then find maxima and minima for $y$.

Tags: trigonometry

I was able to solve it till

$$y = \sqrt{(a^2 + b^2)}\sin(\alpha + x)  +  C.$$

But I don't know how to find maxima and minima from here.

If $C = 0$ then maxima & minima equals the amplitude of the sine curve but when $C$ is non-zero then?

I need help from here onwards.

Comment: $$-1\le\sin(x+\alpha)\le1$$

Comment: As $C$ is constant, you can just add this to the extrema you get for the zero case.

Comment: The graph is just moved up/down by $C$ vertically. With the obvious consequences. Draw graphs.

Comment: @lab-bhattacharjee Ah, that is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Macavity Thanks I get it now. :)

Comment: @henno-brandsma Got it! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

- $\sin(\alpha +x) \in [-1,1]$

  $$ \therefore \quad \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin(\alpha+x) \in \left[ - \sqrt{a^2+b^2}, \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \right]$$

$$ \quad \therefore \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin(\alpha+x)+C \in \left[C- \sqrt{a^2+b^2}, C+ \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\ \right] \quad ,$$ therefore the maximum of $y$ is $_____$, and the minimum of $y$ is $_____$.

Comment: Thanks for the help mate! @alexqwx

Answer (score 0):

**The old way:**

$$y'=a\cos x-b\sin x=0\iff\tan x=\frac ab\iff x=\arctan\frac ab+k\pi.$$

Then

$$\sin\theta=\pm\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},\\\cos\theta=\pm\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},$$ and

$$y=\pm\frac{a^2+b^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}+c=\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+c.$$

The maximum obviously corresponds to the plus sign.